# How to send database to server with HttpPost in Android and check

Tags: android, mysql, wampserver

I am using this code (which I copied from a tutorial) to send some information to the database in MySQL. In the android app:

```
class UploadToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    //Metemos valores al database del Server

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_id", "2"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("COLUMNname", params[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("COLUMNimage", params[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("COLUMNsound", "tercero"));
    try{
        //JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
          //      "POST", params);
        HttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.35/AndroidFileUpload/UpData.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

        is=entity.getContent();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocol","Log_Tag");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("Log Tag", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception es){
        Log.e("Fallo de excep", "IOException");
        es.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

And in the wampserver I use this php code:

```
<?
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "xxxxx";
$DBpass = "xxxxx";
$DBName = "dbsound";
$table = "dbsound";
$conn = new mysqli_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBName) 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$_id=$_POST['_id'];
$COLUMNname=$_POST['COLUMNname'];
$COLUMNimage=$_POST['COLUMNimage'];
$COLUMNsound=$_POST['COLUMNsound'];

mysqli_select_db("$DBName") or die("Unable to select database $DBName");

$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO $table ("_id", "COLUMNname", "$COLUMNimage","COLUMNsound") VALUES(NULL,'$COLUMNname','$COLUMNimage','$COLUMNsound')";

$results = mysqli_query($sqlquery);

if ($conn->query($sqlquery) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sqlquery . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Where in the DBuser and DBpass I put the data of my MySQL.
I don't have any error, but it doesn't appear anything in the database, so how can I know if the data were sent?

Comment: You can know if data is sent correctly by echoing the data and let your android app read those echos/responses and display them. You should start with a script that does nothing with mysql first. Just start with a script that echos the received data.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps  Do you mean after each variable  <?$DBhost = "localhost";?>  put  <? echo $DBhost ?>.   The data isn't sending, maybe the problem is in the user and pass. I have to put the user and pass that I use to enter in the phpMyadmin no?

Comment: $DBhost is not data that is received by the script. It is created by the script. But of course you can echo it. To echo all data received by the script make a php script that only contains `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`

Comment: @greenapps what in theory I have to see is the variables in like a toast in my app? Because nothing happen.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks a lot!! I've solved the problem of check the result converting response.getEntity().getContent() to String; where response is HttpResponse. I got the variables that I pass so the send is ok. There has to be some problems with the database.